# How to use Escape symbol in insert query on oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-insert

Please Consider this Scenario

```
declare 
  lv_sql varchar(4000);
  lv_sql1 varchar(4000);
begin
  lv_sql1 := 'select case_id from tgt where excluded =''N''';
  lv_sql := 'insert into sample values ('||'''select  count(1) from ( '||lv_sql1||')'')';
  execute immediate (lv_sql);
end;
```

Now if i execute this block then it will raise error of Missing COMMA in oracle.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be valid sql, `select count(1) from select case`, I'd expect a parens in there

Comment: `v_sql1')'` should probably be `v_sql1||')'`. But I can't really make sense of the overall construction. Also I'm not sure what escaping has to do with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here; the first one is about the `VALUES` keyword:

```
SQL> insert into aTable values (select count(*) from dual);
insert into aTable values (select count(*) from dual)
                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression


SQL> insert into aTable (select count(*) from dual);

1 row created.
```

the second is that you are missing parentheses:

```
SQL> select count(*) from select 1 from dual;
select count(*) from select 1 from dual
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00903: invalid table name


SQL> select count(*) from (select 1 from dual);

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1
```

For example:

```
SQL> select * from aTable;

no rows selected

SQL> declare
  2      lv_sql1 varchar2(100);
  3      lv_sql  varchar2(100);
  4  begin
  5      lv_sql1 := 'select 1 from dual';
  6      lv_sql  :='insert into aTable (select count(1) from (' ||lv_sql1 || ') )';
  7      --
  8      execute immediate lv_sql;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from aTable;

         N
----------
         1

SQL>
```

With table like yours:

```
SQL> create table tgt(case_id, excluded) as (select 'xxx', 'N' from dual);

Table created.

SQL> create table sample(n number);

Table created.

SQL> declare
  2      lv_sql varchar(4000);
  3      lv_sql1 varchar(4000);
  4  begin
  5      lv_sql1 := 'select case_id from tgt where excluded =''N''';
  6      lv_sql := 'insert into sample (select count(1) from ( '||lv_sql1||'))';
  7      execute immediate (lv_sql);
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from sample;

         N
----------
         1
```